# Javascript web application with connecting Odoo

Tags: javascript, npm, odoo

I would like to design Javascript web application. In that application, I need to show reports dashboard like daily sales report, the data to be fetched from odoo application.

So I used odoo-xmlrpc to connect javascript to odoo.

js.file

```
var Promise = require('promise');
var async = require("async");
var Odoo = require('odoo-xmlrpc');
        var odoo = new Odoo({
            url: 'localhost',
            port: '8063',
            db: 'db_1',
            username: 'admin',
            password: '123'
        });


function color(){
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      odoo.connect(function (err) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err); }
            console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
            var inParams = [];
            inParams.push([[],[]]);
            var params = [];
            params.push(inParams);
            odoo.execute_kw('account.invoice', 'check_func', [[[], []]], function (err, value) {
                if (err) { return console.log(err); }
                console.log('Result: ', value); //Result: Done
                 resolve(value);


            });
        });
  });


}
async function changeColor(newColor) {
  //document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello3"; //this line working
  var result = await color();
  console.log(result, "@@@@@@@@@@@")// Result Done
  var elem = document.getElementById('para').innerHTML="tet"; //This line dot working
}

changeColor('red')
```

check_func() in python

```
@api.multi
def check_func(self):
   return "done"
```

html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script  type="text/javascript" src="/home/priya/Desktop/ra.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 style="text-align:center;">Reports</h2>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<input type="button" onclick="sales_report_retail()" value="Sales report"/> 
<p id="para"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In that odoo.execute_kw(), I used resolve(value). That value is working with in odoo.execute_kw().
  var result = await sales_report_retail_db(); this line value gets correctly but after this line document.getelementbyid is not working.

I need to show that value in web page. So how to correct this?

Comment: I don't see a reason for an error, any particular error log?

Comment: No. There is no error. If the code is   the following means, Hello3 printed in web page                                                      
 async function changeColor(newColor) {
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello3"; //this line working
  var result = await color();
  console.log(result, "@@@@@@@@@@@")// Result Done
}

Comment: No. There is no error. If the code is   the following means, Hello3 printed in web page.                                                      
  document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello3"; //this line working
  var result = await color();                                                                                                                              if the code is the following means, Hello3 is not printed in web page                    
  var result = await color();
document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Hello3"; 

}